# Problem with perl multiline matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use a perl one-liner to update some code that spans multiple lines and am seeing some strange behavior.  Here's a simple text file that shows the problem I'm seeing:

```
ABCD    START
         STOP    EFGH
```

I expected the following to work but it doesn't end up replacing anything:

```
perl -pi -e 's/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/s' input.txt
```

After doing some experimenting I found that the `\s+` in the original regex will match the newline but not any of the whitespace on the 2nd line, and adding a second `\s+` doesn't work either.  So for now I'm doing the following workaround, which is to add an intermediate regex that only removes the newline:

```
perl -pi -e 's/START\s+/START/s' input.txt
```

This creates the following intermediate file:

```
ABCD    START            STOP    EFGH
```

Then I can run the original regex (although the `/s` is no longer needed):

```
perl -pi -e 's/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/s' input.txt
```

This creates the final, desired file:

```
ABCD    REPLACE    EFGH
```

It seems like the intermediate step should not be necessary.   Am I missing something?

Comment: Your Frequently Asked Question is answered in the very first sentence: "perldoc -q match" --> "I'm having trouble matching over more than one line.  What's wrong?"

Comment: `/s` only affects what `.` matches, so none of your `/s`s are needed

Answer (score 23):

`perl -p` processes the file one line at a time. The regex you have is correct, but it is never matched against the multi-line string.

A simple strategy, assuming the file will fit in memory, is to read the whole thing (do this without `-p`):

```
$/ = undef;
$file = <>;
$file =~ s/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/sg;
print $file;
```

Note, I have added the `/g` modifier to specify global replacement.

As a shortcut for all that extra boilerplate, you can use your existing script with the [`-0777`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-0*[_octal%2fhexadecimal_]) option: `perl -0777pi -e 's/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/sg'`. Adding `/g` is still needed if you may need to make multiple replacements within the file.

A hiccup that you might run into, although not with this regex: if the regex were `START.+STOP`, and a file contains multiple START/STOP pairs, greedy matching of `.+` will eat everything from the first START to the last STOP. You can use non-greedy matching (match as little as possible) with `.+?`.

If you want to use the `^` and `$` anchors for line boundaries anywhere in the string, then you also need the `/m` regex modifier.

Comment: Also can't find any info on the `-0`. What does that flag do?

Comment: This had been driving me nuts! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Documentation on the `-0` argument: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D

Answer (score 23):

You were close. You need either `-00` or `-0777`:

```
 perl -0777 -pi -e 's/START\s+/START/' input.txt
```

Comment: And what do `-0777` and `-00` do? I'm reading the perl manpage, but other than those numbers being octal (which was obvious), I can't find any information. Thanks!

Comment: Option `-0` changes the record separator. `777` activates _slurp mode_, if which no record separator is defined, s.t. the entire file is read at once. `0` changes the separator to blank lines.

Comment: Documentation on the `-0` argument: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D

Answer (score 6):

A relatively simple one-liner (reading the file in memory):

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/sg;' input.txt
```

Another alternative (not so simple), not reading the file in memory:

```
perl -ni -e '$a.=$_; \
             if ( $a =~ s/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/s ) { print $a; $a=""; } \
             END{$a && print $a}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -MFile::Slurp -e '$content = read_file(shift); $content =~ s/START\s+STOP/REPLACE/s; print $content' input.txt
```

Comment: Whyever would you have people use a non-standard module for something that a single simple command-line will take care of completely?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner that doesn't read the entire file into memory at once:

```
perl -i -ne 'if (($x = $last . $_) =~ s/START\n\s*STOP/REPLACE/) \
  { print $x; $last = ""; } else { print $last; $last = $_; } \
  print $last if eof ARGV' input.txt
```

Comment: Nice, although I don't think ARGV is doing anything and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

`-g` is an alias for `-0777`, and is IMO more readable.

```
perl -g -pi -e 's/START\s+/START/' input.txt
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-g