# Perl regexp match across multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

If I have the following data:

```
<br/>
    help can be found...
```

So I've got this with respects to the actual data:

```
<br/>\n\s\s\s\shelp can be found
```

I can't figure out why, but Perl is not finding these matches.  I'm using the following code:

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0];

open(INFILE,  "<",  $filename);

while (<INFILE>){
    if (/(\<br\/\>.*\s{4}[A-Z])/msi){
        print $1."\n";
 }
}
```

to test if Perl returns the parts in my text document that match this regexp, but it not finding them.  I can't see what is wrong with my regexp.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm trying to get Perl to match across the newline character but not working.

Comment: You're processing each line individually. Have a look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862461/problem-with-perl-multiline-matching?rq=1.

Comment: I thought the <INFILE> slurps the file.  It still doesn;t work if I do $/ = undef;

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot He's got the i option on so it will

Comment: What should my code changed to then for this regexp to work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<INFILE>` in a while loop loads each line into `$_` individually. So to match across lines you need to set `$/` to undef. You also then need to move the while loop to the regex and use the global flag to set multiple matches.

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0];

$/ =undef;

open(INFILE,  "<",  $filename);

my $file = <INFILE>;

while ($file =~ /(\<br\/\>.*\s{4}[A-Z])/msig){
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

Comment: This code tells me that use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)

Comment: This comes up with "main::line" used only once: possible typo. Also comes up with use of uninitialzed value $line in pattern match

Comment: Thanks. but this just prints the entire file, not just the pattern matches.

Comment: thats probably because the regex is matching most of the file. I'm not quite sure what the `.*` is doing but this will match from first `<br>` to last space followed by a letter.

Comment: Working now - corrected the regexo /(\<br\/\>\n\s{4}[A-Z])/.  Thanks.