# Perl not matching regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove all the comments in a bunch of SGF files, and have come up with the following perl command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/P?C\[(?:[^\]\\]++|\\.)*+\]//gm' *.sgf
```

I'm trying to match and remove a C or PC followed by a left bracket, then characters that aren't right brackets (if they are they have to be escaped with a `\`) and then a right bracket.

I'm trying to match the following examples:

`C[HelloBot9 [-\]: GTP Engine for HelloBot9 (white): HelloBot version 0.6.26.08]`

```
PC[IA [-\]: GTP Engine for IA (black): GNU Go version 3.7.11
]
```

`C[person [-\]: \\\]]`

```
C[AyaMC [3k\]: GTP Engine for AyaMC (black): Aya version 6.61 : If you pass, AyaMC 
will pass. When AyaMC does not, please remove all dead stones.]
```

And some examples that shouldn't be matched:

`XYZ[Other stuff \]]`

`C[stuff\]`

`PC[stuff\\\]`

The regex works in several online regex testers (including a few that state they are perl regex testers), but for some reason doesn't work on the command line. Help is appreciated.

Comment: The online regex testers I've seen all use PCRE, not Perl regex, so the results won't necessarily be the same. Also, the `/m` modifier is useless because you don't use any `^` or `$` anchors; see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#*m*).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ah, that makes more sense. I still have no idea how to make this work though.

Comment: When I run your code on the first set of examples, it works. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Aha! I found the issue, sort of! It was because I dropped the newline when copying the test cases over; so now my problem is how to make the newline not a problem.

EDIT: Adding `s` to flags doesn't work

Comment: Can you update the examples in your question? I assume you mean there's a newline in the middle of `C[...]`, in which case I'll refer you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5862461/176646).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you, that worked! I updated the test cases to be clearer too.

Comment: So, you used `perl -0777pi -e` and it worked? Also, a bit optimized pattern will look like `s/P?C\[[^]\\]*(?:\\.[^]\\]*+)*]//sg` (if a newline cannot be escaped, you do not even need the `s` modifier in this case).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that's what I used. Thanks for the optimised one, but it wasn't really necessary for me. The perl command I used took an acceptable amount of time (2 minutes at most if I had to guess) to execute in a directory with 35K files; however, if you want, you could post it as an answer to help anyone else who needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `perl` with `-0777` option to make sure that contents spanning across lines and matching the pattern can be found.  So, using `perl -0777pi -e` instead of `perl -pi -e` will solve the issue.

I would also suggest optimizing the pattern a bit by unrolling the alternation group, thus, making matching process "linear":

```
s/P?C\[[^]\\]*(?:\\.[^]\\]*+)*]//sg
```

Note that if `PC` should be matched as a whole word, add `\b` before `P`.

**Pattern details**:

- `P?C\[`  - either `PC[` or `C[` literal char sequence
- `[^]\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `\` and `]`
- `(?:\\.[^]\\]*+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\\.` - a literal `\` and then any char (`.`)
  - `[^]\\]*+` - 0+ chars other than `]` and `\` (matched possessively, no backtracking into the pattern)
- `]` - a literal `]` symbol (note it does not have to be escaped outside the character class to denote a literal closing bracket)